# Xml parser with child elements

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have the following xml format and wanted to read the elements in java . 'm very new to xml parsing.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<IDV><exshowroomPrice>48800</exshowroomPrice><idv_amount>46360</idv_amount><idv_amount_min>39406</idv_amount_min><idv_amount_max>53314</idv_amount_max><exshowroomPrice_min>41480</exshowroomPrice_min><exshowroomPrice_max>56120</exshowroomPrice_max><outputmessage></outputmessage></IDV>
<string>
```

I have added this and after that unable to extract the elements.

```
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                                        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                                        InputSource is = new InputSource();
                                        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(responsebuffer.toString()));
                                        Document doc = db.parse(is);
                                        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                                        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent());



   NodeList nodes = doc.getChildNodes();
                                    Node no1 = (Node) nodes.item(0);
                                    if (doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().getLength() > 0) {



                                            if (nodes.item(0).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(0);
                                                NodeList nl =element.getElementsByTagName("exshowroomPrice");

                                                 System.out.println(((Node)nl).getNodeValue());
                                            }


                                    }
```

o/p:`<IDV><exshowroomPrice>48800</exshowroomPrice><idv_amount>46360</idv_amount><idv_amount_min>39406</idv_amount_min><idv_amount_max>53314</idv_amount_max><exshowroomPrice_min>41480</exshowroomPrice_min><exshowroomPrice_max>56120</exshowroomPrice_max><outputmessage></outputmessage></IDV>`

Kindly help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With DOM, with JAXB, with RegEx?

Comment: There's an infinite number of xml parsers for java. Have you done anything yourself before posting this?

Comment: @f1sh, Yes tried a lot with different processes. could not get success.

Comment: @zeet so after you provided some code it's apparent that you already parsed your xml content to a ``Document``. That offers your some methods. What are you stuck on?

Comment: Wanted to get each and every element of the string. But Did not get the proper way...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but your XML is malformed (it should end with ).

That said, the code to parse your document is correct, now I think the simplest way to extract individual elements would be to use class XPathAPI.

For instance:

```
        Node node = XPathAPI.selectSingleNode(doc, "//string/IDV/exshowroomPrice");
        System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
```

UPDATE:

Actually, XPathAPI is not a standard, but you can use XPath:

```
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String val = (String) xpath.evaluate("//string/IDV/exshowroomPrice/text()", doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: @zeet Oh, yeah: the last line should be </string>, not <string>

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer.

```
try {

                                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                                    InputSource is = new InputSource();
                                    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(responsebuffer.toString()));
                                    Document document = db.parse(is);
                                    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                                    //System.out.println(document.getDocumentElement().getTextContent());

                                    StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                    xmlStringBuilder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
                                    xmlStringBuilder.append(document.getDocumentElement().getTextContent());
                                    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                                    Document doc = db.parse(input);

                                    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("IDV");
                                    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                                        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                                        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


 System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("exshowroomPrice").item(0).getTextContent());
 System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("idv_amount").item(0).getTextContent());
  System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("idv_amount_min").item(0).getTextContent());
  System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("idv_amount_max").item(0).getTextContent());
 System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("exshowroomPrice_min").item(0).getTextContent());
 System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("exshowroomPrice_max").item(0).getTextContent());
 System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("outputmessage").item(0).getTextContent());




                                        }
                                    }

                                    //getElementsByTagName("exshowroomPrice")

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```